# App fatal error with iOS9 public beta 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-9-beta3

I just installed the latest iOS9 public beta (3) on my iPhone 6, and the game I'm developing, while compiling without errors in xcode 7 beta 4, shots down immediatly after the splash screen with the following fatal error:

[image]

[image]

The game works fine on iOS9 public beta 2, so I'm guessing this has to do with the new beta. While it's normal for a beta to behave like this with certain apps, I'm wondering if there's something about my code that could be the issue (other apps and games work perfectly in this new beta).

Other stack overflow answers on "dyld errors" mention that cleaning, then running the project, or deleting Xcode cache (com.apple.dt.Xcode) the cleaning and running should fix it, but nothing works in my case. Also, the new flag "unable bitcode" is set to "no".

In fact, the error messages are undecipherable to me, is there something I could try to fix this terrible bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see anything in the device log that's related to your app?  (Xcode Devices window....)

Comment: Beta 5 has been out for a while now. Update and see if you still have the issue. It's important to stay up-to-date.

Comment: I'm on the public beta feed, using ios9 public beta 3 which, I believe, is the same than dev beta 5.
@PhillipMills Mills, I'm trying to find a cable at work to try it. Will update the question with details when I have them :)

Comment: Ooooh, were you talking about xcode beta 5? if so, I'm installing it right now, hopefully the problem will be solved then... thanks

Comment: You were right @rmaddy, xcode beta 5 fixes it... Thanks a lot!